# how to pass values from a javascript function to a variable

Tags: javascript

I need to pass the value of the javascript function below to a variable in javascript but its only shows the value in a console. it does not pass the function values **(somevar)** to the **display** variables

```
function functionThatNeedsRowsData(values){
var somevar = values;
// console shows the value
console.log(somevar);

}

//Now display the value of (somevar) in a function and pass it to a variable not working
var display= functionThatNeedsRowsData();
```

Comment: Your function doesn't *return* anything.  What are you expecting it to return and why?

Comment: Are you just asking about `return`? You want to return a value from `functionThatNeedsRowsData`? What aren't you passing data into that function, and why aren't you returning from it?

Comment: There is a minimum effort and learning of a language i expect, otherwise i downvote. This question would be avoided by almost **any** javascript tutorial or programming tutorial in general.

Comment: Yeah.. this is something that is handled by learning tools which, if you're not aware of how to return a value from a function, you need to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the value inside the function:

```
return somevar;
```

Comment: i have already done that  by returning the value but with no luck. the value is asynchronous

Comment: @Markjames11: *"the value is asynchronous"*  then see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)